# How do you debug PHP scripts?

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

How do you debug **PHP** scripts?

I am aware of basic debugging such as using the Error Reporting. The breakpoint debugging in **PHPEclipse** is also quite useful.

What is the **best** (in terms of fast and easy) way to debug in phpStorm or any other IDE?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640421/i-need-to-debug-php-what-is-my-best-choice

Comment: [Debugging locally in Win/Mac (with a WAMP/MAMP stack and PHPStorm)](http://www.dev-metal.com/setup-use-xdebug-phpstorm-locally-windows-78-mac-os-x/)

Comment: I believe this is a great question! When you don't know how to approach PHP debugging, you don't even know how to word your question, don't know how to be more precise than this. So, it may not obey Stack's rules, but it sure helps us, beginners, a lot!

Comment: from php5.4 onwards introduced new command line interface debugger called phpdbg(http://phpdbg.com/).  PHP5.6 will come with default phpdbg.

Comment: I am using firephp, it is really awesome as it sends the message to the console log(like console.log()); check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rd5ZwWU-YD4

Comment: Ever heard of XDebug ? :)

Comment: Many seem to use PHPStorm, it's lighter weight than Eclipse PDT and simpler.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Try [Eclipse PDT](https://eclipse.org/pdt/) to setup an Eclipse environment that has debugging features like you mentioned. The ability to step into the code is a much better way to debug then the old method of var_dump and print at various points to see where your flow goes wrong. When all else fails though and all I have is SSH and vim I still `var_dump()`/`die()` to find where the code goes south.

Comment: You should use this function: kill( $data ) { die( var_dump ( $data ) ); } It saves typing 10 characters, best function i have ever written tbh:)

Comment: Try https://github.com/tomasfejfar/enhanced-dump :)

Comment: Is there a way to beautify the "var_dump" ?

Comment: @Tareck117 Yes. [You can install xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/install)

Comment: @Tareck an alternative to prettify debug output : $v2 = array ("h"=>5, "o"=>10, "p"=>11); $str = serialize($v2);
echo "<pre>" .print_r(unserialize($str), true) . "</pre>";

Comment: @Tareck117 Yes, use ```var_export``` instead

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch I raise you to `kill($data) { echo "<pre>"; var_dump($data); echo "</pre>"; exit; }`

Comment: Link is "recoverable" via the incredible [Web Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150507142619/http://dev.piwik.org/trac/wiki/HowToSetupDevelopmentEnvironmentWindows), last check as of 7 may '15.

Comment: Don't bother with the Web Archive, since this answer was created Eclipse have created a proper PHP Development Environment - https://eclipse.org/pdt/. I have updated the answer to suit.

Answer (score 80):

You can use Firephp an add-on to firebug to debug php in the same environment as javascript.

I also use [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) mentioned earlier for profiling php.

Comment: And here's a quick guide to using FirePHP: http://www.sitepoint.com/debug-php-firebug-firephp/

Answer (score 38):

This is my little debug environment:

```
error_reporting(-1);
assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, 1);
assert_options(ASSERT_WARNING, 0);
assert_options(ASSERT_BAIL, 0);
assert_options(ASSERT_QUIET_EVAL, 0);
assert_options(ASSERT_CALLBACK, 'assert_callcack');
set_error_handler('error_handler');
set_exception_handler('exception_handler');
register_shutdown_function('shutdown_handler');

function assert_callcack($file, $line, $message) {
    throw new Customizable_Exception($message, null, $file, $line);
}

function error_handler($errno, $error, $file, $line, $vars) {
    if ($errno === 0 || ($errno & error_reporting()) === 0) {
        return;
    }

    throw new Customizable_Exception($error, $errno, $file, $line);
}

function exception_handler(Exception $e) {
    // Do what ever!
    echo '<pre>', print_r($e, true), '</pre>';
    exit;
}

function shutdown_handler() {
    try {
        if (null !== $error = error_get_last()) {
            throw new Customizable_Exception($error['message'], $error['type'], $error['file'], $error['line']);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        exception_handler($e);
    }
}

class Customizable_Exception extends Exception {
    public function __construct($message = null, $code = null, $file = null, $line = null) {
        if ($code === null) {
            parent::__construct($message);
        } else {
            parent::__construct($message, $code);
        }
        if ($file !== null) {
            $this->file = $file;
        }
        if ($line !== null) {
            $this->line = $line;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That saved my day. (I just had to remove that E_STRICT)

Comment: `assert_callcack` heh

Answer (score 32):

Xdebug and the DBGp plugin for Notepad++ for heavy duty bug hunting, FirePHP for lightweight stuff. Quick and dirty? Nothing beats [dBug](http://dbug.ospinto.com/).

Comment: The DBGp plugin doesn't work with the current version of notepad++/xdebug and there are no plans to fix it. You can see my discussion with the creator linked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172253/xdebug-notepad-dbpg-plugin-local-and-global-context-not-showing/18187323#18187323)

Answer (score 26):

[XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) is essential for development. I install it before any other extension. It gives you stack traces on any error and you can enable profiling easily.

For a quick look at a data structure use [`var_dump()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). Don't use `print_r()` because you'll have to surround it with `<pre>` and it only prints one var at a time.

```
<?php var_dump(__FILE__, __LINE__, $_REQUEST); ?>
```

For a real debugging environment the best I've found is [Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/Products/komodo_ide/index.mhtml) but it costs $$.

Answer (score 19):

PhpEd is really good. You can step into/over/out of functions. You can run ad-hoc code, inspect variables, change variables. It is amazing.

Comment: I have used PhpEd and I have no kind words for it when compared to a real IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse, nor does this comment add anything useful to the question. -1

Comment: I tried most of the IDEs (including Zend, NetBeans and Eclipse) before buying PhpED Professional because it was the best by a mile and a half. This was a few years ago, so the others may have since improved, but at the time most of them were painfully slow because they were written in Java. I don't understand how someone can have "no kind words for it" when (for me) it was so clearly the best, the decision was a no-brainer.

Answer (score 17):

1) I use print_r(). In TextMate, I have a snippet for 'pre' which expands to this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r();
echo "</pre>";
```

2) I use Xdebug, but haven't been able to get the GUI to work right on my Mac. It at least prints out a readable version of the stack trace.

Comment: I'm sure you mean echo "</pre>"; at the end though.

Comment: You can also pass 'true' into the function so it returns the string. It means you can do this: `echo '<pre>', print_r($var, true), '</pre>';`

Answer (score 16):

I've used the [Zend Studio (5.5)](http://www.zend.com/products/studio/), together with [Zend Platform](http://www.zend.com/en/products/platform/). That gives proper debugging, breakpoints/stepping over the code etc., although at a price.

Answer (score 16):

In all honesty, a combination of print and print_r() to print out the variables. I know that many prefer to use other more advanced methods but I find this the easiest to use.

I will say that I didn't fully appreciate this until I did some Microprocessor programming at Uni and was not able to use even this.

Comment: I am glad you mentioned print as well as print_r, I use a basic print to see if the code executed to a certain point, which helps isolating the problem.

Comment: I use both print and var_dump(). I use print to display debug messages and information and var_dump to indicate the state of variables as things progress.

Answer (score 14):

[Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/), by Derick Rethans, is very good. I used it some time ago and found it was not so easy to install. Once you're done, you won't understand how you managed without it :-)

There is a good article on [Zend Developer Zone](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2803-introducing-xdebug) (installing on Linux doesn't seem any easier) and even a [Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/3960), which I never used.

Comment: Its not just installing that's frustrating. Configuring Xdebug to work with Eclipse can be a nightmare. I was able to get Xdebug installed on CentOS 5 but EclipsePDT+Xdebug dont want to co-operate :(

Answer (score 11):

I use Netbeans with XDebug. 
Check it out at its website for docs on how to configure it.
http://php.netbeans.org/

Answer (score 11):

I use Netbeans with XDebug and the [Easy XDebug FireFox Add-on](http://www.elime.be/easyxdebug.htm)

The add-on is essential when you debug MVC projects, because the normal way XDebug runs in Netbeans is to register the dbug session via the url. With the add-on installed in FireFox, you would set your Netbeans project properties -> Run Configuratuion -> Advanced and select "Do Not Open Web Browser" You can now set your break points and start the debugging session with Ctrl-F5 as usual. Open FireFox and right-click the Add-on icon in the right bottom corner to start monitoring for breakpoints. When the code reaches the breakpoint it will stop and you can inspect your variable states and call-stack.

Answer (score 10):

Output buffering is very useful if you don't want to mess up your output. I do this in a one-liner which I can comment/uncomment at will

```
 ob_start();var_dump(); user_error(ob_get_contents()); ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: This may be useful http://www.devarticles.in/php/useful-function-to-output-debug-data-in-php/

Answer (score 9):

PhpEdit has a built in debugger, but I usually end up using echo(); and print_r(); the old fashioned way!!

Answer (score 8):

For the really gritty problems that would be too time consuming to use print_r/echo to figure out I use my IDE's (PhpEd) debugging feature.  Unlike other IDEs I've used, PhpEd requires pretty much no setup.  the only reason I don't use it for any problems I encounter is that it's *painfully* slow.  I'm not sure that slowness is specific to PhpEd or any php debugger.  PhpEd is not free but I believe it uses one of the open-source debuggers (like XDebug previously mentioned) anyway.  The benefit with PhpEd, again, is that it requires no setup which I have found really pretty tedious in the past.

Comment: The PHPEd debugger is actually written by the same guy who wrote PHPEd and I'm pretty sure it's not open source. At least PHPEd doesn't ship with the source but instead compiled .so's and .dll's.

Answer (score 4):

Manual debugging is generally quicker for me - `var_dump()` and `debug_print_backtrace()` are all the tools you need to arm your logic with.

Answer (score 3):

Well, to some degree it depends on where things are going south. That's the first thing I try to isolate, and then I'll use echo/print_r() as necessary.

NB: You guys know that you can pass true as a second argument to print_r() and it'll return the output instead of printing it? E.g.:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($var, true)."</pre>";
```

Comment: I just wrap that in a function called debug. So then I can do debug($var);

Answer (score 3):

I often use CakePHP when Rails isn't possible. To debug errors I usually find the `error.log` in the tmp folder and tail it in the terminal with the command...

```
tail -f app/tmp/logs/error.log
```

It give's you running dialog from cake of what is going on, which is pretty handy, if you want to output something to it mid code you can use.

```
$this->log('xxxx');
```

This can usually give you a good idea of what is going on/wrong.

Answer (score 2):

print_r( debug_backtrace() );

or something like that :-)

Comment: Just like the one here http://www.devarticles.in/php/useful-function-to-output-debug-data-in-php/

Answer (score 2):

Komodo IDE works well with xdebug, even for the remore debugging. It needs minimum amount of configuration. All you need is a version of php that Komodo can use locally to step through the code on a breakpoint. If you have the script imported into komodo project, then you can set breakpoints with a mouse-click just how you would set it inside eclipse for debugging a java program.
Remote debugging is obviously more tricky to get it to work correctly ( you might have to map the remote url with a php script in your workspace ) than a local debugging setup which is pretty easy to configure if you are on a MAC or a linux desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Nusphere is also a good debugger for php
[nusphere](http://www.nusphere.com/download.php.ide.htm)

Answer (score 2):

There are many PHP debugging techniques that can save you countless hours when coding. An effective but basic debugging technique is to simply turn on error reporting. Another slightly more advanced technique involves using print statements, which can help pinpoint more elusive bugs by displaying what is actually going onto the screen. PHPeclipse is an Eclipse plug-in that can highlight common syntax errors and can be used in conjunction with a debugger to set breakpoints.

```
display_errors = Off
error_reporting = E_ALL 
display_errors = On
```

and also used

```
error_log();
console_log();
```

Answer (score 1):

In a production environment, I log relevant data to the server's error log with error_log().

Comment: and than tail -f ... works great

Answer (score 1):

i use zend studio for eclipse with the built in debugger. Its still slow compared to debugging with eclipse pdt with xdebug. Hopefully they will fix those issues, the speed has improved over the recent releases but still stepping over things takes 2-3 seconds.
The zend firefox toolbar really makes things easy (debug next page, current page, etc). Also it provides a profiler that will benchmark your code and provide pie-charts, execution time, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The most of bugs can be found easily by simply `var_dump`ing some of key variables, but it obviously depends on what kind of application you develop.

For a more complex algorithms the step/breakpoint/watch functions are very helpful (if not necessary)

Answer (score 1):

#### [PHP DBG](http://phpdbg.com/)

The Interactive Stepthrough PHP Debugger implemented as a SAPI module which can give give you complete control over the environment without impacting the functionality or performance of your code. It aims to be a lightweight, powerful, easy to use debugging platform for PHP 5.4+ and it's shipped out-of-box with PHP 5.6.

Features includes:

- Stepthrough Debugging
- Flexible Breakpoints (Class Method, Function, File:Line, Address, Opcode)
- Easy Access to PHP with built-in eval()
- Easy Access to Currently Executing Code
- Userland API
- SAPI Agnostic - Easily Integrated
- PHP Configuration File Support
- JIT Super Globals - Set Your Own!!
- Optional readline Support - Comfortable Terminal Operation
- Remote Debugging Support - Bundled Java GUI
- Easy Operation

See the screenshots:

[image: PHP DBG - Stepthrough Debugging - screenshot]

[image: PHP DBG - Stepthrough Debugging - screenshot]

Home page: http://phpdbg.com/

#### [PHP Error](http://phperror.net/) - Better error reporting for PHP

This is very easy to use library (actually a file) to debug your PHP scripts.

The only thing that you need to do is to include one file as below (at the beginning on your code):

```
require('php_error.php');
\php_error\reportErrors();
```

Then all errors will give you info such as backtrace, code context, function arguments, server variables, etc. For example:

[image: PHP Error | Improve Error Reporting for PHP - screenshot of backtrace]
[image: PHP Error | Improve Error Reporting for PHP - screenshot of backtrace]
[image: PHP Error | Improve Error Reporting for PHP - screenshot of backtrace]

Features include:

- trivial to use, it's just one file
- errors displayed in the browser for normal and ajaxy requests
- AJAX requests are paused, allowing you to automatically re-run them
- makes errors as strict as possible (encourages code quality, and tends to improve performance)
- code snippets across the whole stack trace
- provides more information (such as full function signatures)
- fixes some error messages which are just plain wrong
- syntax highlighting
- looks pretty!
- customization
- manually turn it on and off
- run specific sections without error reporting
- ignore files allowing you to avoid highlighting code in your stack trace
- application files; these are prioritized when an error strikes!

Home page: http://phperror.net/

GitHub: https://github.com/JosephLenton/PHP-Error

My fork (with extra fixes): https://github.com/kenorb-contrib/PHP-Error

#### [DTrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace)

If your system supports [DTrace dynamic tracing](http://php.net/manual/en/features.dtrace.php) (installed by default on OS X) and your PHP is compiled with the DTrace probes enabled (`--enable-dtrace`) which should be by default, this command can help you to debug PHP script with no time:

```
sudo dtrace -qn 'php*:::function-entry { printf("%Y: PHP function-entry:\t%s%s%s() in %s:%d\n", walltimestamp, copyinstr(arg3), copyinstr(arg4), copyinstr(arg0), basename(copyinstr(arg1)), (int)arg2); }'
```

So given the following alias has been added into your *rc* files (e.g. `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_aliases`):

```
alias trace-php='sudo dtrace -qn "php*:::function-entry { printf(\"%Y: PHP function-entry:\t%s%s%s() in %s:%d\n\", walltimestamp, copyinstr(arg3), copyinstr(arg4), copyinstr(arg0), basename(copyinstr(arg1)), (int)arg2); }"'
```

you may trace your script with easy to remember alias: `trace-php`.

Here is more advanced dtrace script, just save it into `dtruss-php.d`, make it executable (`chmod +x dtruss-php.d`) and run:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -Zs
# See: https://github.com/kenorb/dtruss-lamp/blob/master/dtruss-php.d

#pragma D option quiet

php*:::compile-file-entry
{
    printf("%Y: PHP compile-file-entry:\t%s (%s)\n", walltimestamp, basename(copyinstr(arg0)), copyinstr(arg1));
}

php*:::compile-file-return
{
    printf("%Y: PHP compile-file-return:\t%s (%s)\n", walltimestamp, basename(copyinstr(arg0)), basename(copyinstr(arg1)));
}

php*:::error
{
    printf("%Y: PHP error message:\t%s in %s:%d\n", walltimestamp, copyinstr(arg0), basename(copyinstr(arg1)), (int)arg2);
}

php*:::exception-caught
{
    printf("%Y: PHP exception-caught:\t%s\n", walltimestamp, copyinstr(arg0));
}

php*:::exception-thrown
{
    printf("%Y: PHP exception-thrown:\t%s\n", walltimestamp, copyinstr(arg0));
}

php*:::execute-entry
{
    printf("%Y: PHP execute-entry:\t%s:%d\n", walltimestamp, basename(copyinstr(arg0)), (int)arg1);
}

php*:::execute-return
{
    printf("%Y: PHP execute-return:\t%s:%d\n", walltimestamp, basename(copyinstr(arg0)), (int)arg1);
}

php*:::function-entry
{
    printf("%Y: PHP function-entry:\t%s%s%s() in %s:%d\n", walltimestamp, copyinstr(arg3), copyinstr(arg4), copyinstr(arg0), basename(copyinstr(arg1)), (int)arg2);
}

php*:::function-return
{
    printf("%Y: PHP function-return:\t%s%s%s() in %s:%d\n", walltimestamp, copyinstr(arg3), copyinstr(arg4), copyinstr(arg0), basename(copyinstr(arg1)), (int)arg2);
}

php*:::request-shutdown
{
    printf("%Y: PHP request-shutdown:\t%s at %s via %s\n", walltimestamp, basename(copyinstr(arg0)), copyinstr(arg1), copyinstr(arg2));
}

php*:::request-startup
{
    printf("%Y, PHP request-startup:\t%s at %s via %s\n", walltimestamp, basename(copyinstr(arg0)), copyinstr(arg1), copyinstr(arg2));
}
```

<sup>Home page: [dtruss-lamp](https://github.com/kenorb/dtruss-lamp) at GitHub</sup>

Here is simple usage:

1. Run: `sudo dtruss-php.d`.
2. On another terminal run: `php -r "phpinfo();"`.

To test that, you can go to any docroot with `index.php` and run PHP builtin server by:

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

After that you can access the site at http://localhost:8080/ (or choose whatever port is convenient for you). From there access some pages to see the trace output.

Note: Dtrace is available on OS X by default, on Linux you probably need [dtrace4linux](https://github.com/dtrace4linux/linux) or check for some other [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2059311/55075).

See: [Using PHP and DTrace](http://php.net/manual/en/features.dtrace.dtrace.php) at php.net

---

#### [SystemTap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemTap)

Alternatively check for SystemTap tracing by installing SystemTap SDT development package (e.g. `yum install systemtap-sdt-devel`).

Here is example script (`all_probes.stp`) for tracing all core PHP static probe points throughout the duration of a running PHP script with SystemTap:

```
probe process("sapi/cli/php").provider("php").mark("compile__file__entry") {
    printf("Probe compile__file__entry\n");
    printf("  compile_file %s\n", user_string($arg1));
    printf("  compile_file_translated %s\n", user_string($arg2));
}
probe process("sapi/cli/php").provider("php").mark("compile__file__return") {
    printf("Probe compile__file__return\n");
    printf("  compile_file %s\n", user_string($arg1));
    printf("  compile_file_translated %s\n", user_string($arg2));
}
probe process("sapi/cli/php").provider("php").mark("error") {
    printf("Probe error\n");
    printf("  errormsg %s\n", user_string($arg1));
    printf("  request_file %s\n", user_string($arg2));
    printf("  lineno %d\n", $arg3);
}
probe process("sapi/cli/php").provider("php").mark("exception__caught") {
    printf("Probe exception__caught\n");
    printf("  classname %s\n", user_string($arg1));
}
probe process("sapi/cli/php").provider("php").mark("exception__thrown") {
    printf("Probe exception__thrown\n");
    printf("  classname %s\n", user_string($arg1));
}
probe process("sapi/cli/php").provider("php").mark("execute__entry") {
    printf("Probe execute__entry\n");
    printf("  request_file %s\n", user_string($arg1));
    printf("  lineno %d\n", $arg2);
}
probe process("sapi/cli/php").provider("php").mark("execute__return") {
    printf("Probe execute__return\n");
    printf("  request_file %s\n", user_string($arg1));
    printf("  lineno %d\n", $arg2);
}
probe process("sapi/cli/php").provider("php").mark("function__entry") {
    printf("Probe function__entry\n");
    printf("  function_name %s\n", user_string($arg1));
    printf("  request_file %s\n", user_string($arg2));
    printf("  lineno %d\n", $arg3);
    printf("  classname %s\n", user_string($arg4));
    printf("  scope %s\n", user_string($arg5));
}
probe process("sapi/cli/php").provider("php").mark("function__return") {
    printf("Probe function__return: %s\n", user_string($arg1));
    printf(" function_name %s\n", user_string($arg1));
    printf("  request_file %s\n", user_string($arg2));
    printf("  lineno %d\n", $arg3);
    printf("  classname %s\n", user_string($arg4));
    printf("  scope %s\n", user_string($arg5));
}
probe process("sapi/cli/php").provider("php").mark("request__shutdown") {
    printf("Probe request__shutdown\n");
    printf("  file %s\n", user_string($arg1));
    printf("  request_uri %s\n", user_string($arg2));
    printf("  request_method %s\n", user_string($arg3));
}
probe process("sapi/cli/php").provider("php").mark("request__startup") {
    printf("Probe request__startup\n");
    printf("  file %s\n", user_string($arg1));
    printf("  request_uri %s\n", user_string($arg2));
    printf("  request_method %s\n", user_string($arg3));
}
```

Usage:

```
stap -c 'sapi/cli/php test.php' all_probes.stp
```

See: [Using SystemTap with PHP DTrace Static Probes](http://php.net/manual/en/features.dtrace.systemtap.php) at php.net

Answer (score 0):

+1 for print_r(). Use it to dump out the contents of an object or variable. To make it more readable, do it with a pre tag so you don't need to view source.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrayOrObject);
```

Also var_dump($thing) - this is very useful to see the type of subthings

Comment: An extended version can be found here http://www.devarticles.in/php/useful-function-to-output-debug-data-in-php/

Comment: Here is a refined version http://www.devarticles.in/php/useful-function-to-output-debug-data-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the issue I like a combination of error_reporting(E_ALL) mixed with echo tests (to find the offending line/file the error happened in initally; you KNOW it's not always the line/file php tells you right?), IDE brace matching (to resolve "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end" issues), and print_r(); exit; dumps (real programmers view the source ;p).

You also can't beat phpdebug (check sourceforge) with "memory_get_usage();" and "memory_get_peak_usage();" to find the problem areas.

Answer (score 0):

The integrated debuggers where you can watch the values of variable change as you step through code are really cool. They do, however, require software setup on the server and a certain amount of configuration on the client. Both of which require periodic maintenance to keep in good working order.

A print_r is easy to write and is guaranteed to work in any setup.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I find create a custom log function able to save on file, store debug info, and eventually re-print on a common footer.

You can also override common Exception class, so that this type of debugging is semi-automated.