# Find who calls a method in PHP's class

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out which class called a method in another class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214043/find-out-which-class-called-a-method-in-another-class)

Hello everyone,

I have a class and I can't find where his object creates.
I mean, can I somehow find out who calls his constructor?

Thanks a lot,
Andrey.

Comment: @Gordon: I think this question differs a bit because of "I have a class and I can't find where his object creates" and therefore (imo) debug_backtrace() isn't the single best answer. You shouldn't _change_ existing code to get a class/dependency/call graph.

Comment: @VolkerK actually debug_backtrace is the worst answer. If the aim of the OP is to know the caller in the callee, then the caller should be passed to the callee and not the callee trying to find out the caller from the backtrace. And you are right suggesting a debugger/profiler for your reading of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$trace = debug_backtrace();
echo "<pre>".print_r($trace[1])."</pre>"; 
//see all the displays '1' is the referrer '0' is self
echo $callingfunction = $trace[1]['function'];
echo $callingclass = $trace[1]['class'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [debug_backtrace()](http://docs.php.net/debug_backtrace) or even better a tracer/profiler like [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) to gather the information and e.g. [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) to visualize it.