# Determine calling scope in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Is there a way to determine the scope in which a function is called from inside the function itself?  (Or method; I'll use function to mean either in the remainder of the post.)

What I do not want is to have to pass `__FILE__` or `__CLASS__` constants into the function.  This information is available in stack traces, etc. so I know it's floating around somewhere, but I'd like to know how to introspect it at runtime without throwing exceptions.

If there are any performance particularities for a solution, I'd like to know about those as well.

There are two use-cases I'm interested in.

1. Determine which file / line / function called my function
2. Determine the class type that originated the function call

Basically what I want is this:

```
class util
{
    public static function checkScope()
    {
        echo $magic_scope_stuff;
    }

    public static function blah()
    {
        util::checkScope();
    }
}

util::checkScope(); // main, line 14
util::blah(); // class util, line 9
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out which class called a method in another class.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214043/find-out-which-class-called-a-method-in-another-class)

Comment: This question gets asked every now and then, so there should be some more duplicates for it. If you want that desperately, abuse `debug_backtrace` but in general, having that need is a design smell. Implementing such a feature into PHP has been discussed and rejected on php.internals as well: http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=125313473914294&w=3

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for the reading material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [`debug_backtrace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) for that.

The resulting array gives you a call trace from the entry point until the invocation of `debug_backtrace`.

Comment: actually `debug_backtrace` is debugging and not to get caller scope. It can do that, but it's definitely not a function to control application flow

Comment: @Gordon. True. It's for retrieving debugging information. Hence the prefix. I don't encourage it (same overhead as exceptions), but it's possible to use for flow control.

Comment: @Gordon Yes, that's the distinction I was trying to make; thanks.