# Get calling scope in a PHP function?

Tags: php, scope

Can I access the scope of the calling environment from within a called function?

For example, I would like to access `__LINE__` in a logging function but it needs to be the `__LINE__` from the calling environment. I would also like to have some way of calling `get_defined_vars()` to get the callers variables.

In both examples it saves having to have an extra argument.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you *could* do this, you'd eventually realize what a bad idea it is (outside of logging, anyway).

Comment: @Renesis: Not only that. Being able to get the calling scope would completely defeat the purpose of passing parameters.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get the variables defined in stack frames below the top one.

Comment: `debug_backtrace()` will at least give you the call stack and line numbers as an array with a few extra tidbits.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine calling scope in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4832011/1255289)

Comment: @miken32 The other question appears to only want to class and line number. I say here "I would also like to have some way [...] to get the callers variables.". The answers to both questions may be mucking around with `debug_backtrace` however the questions are different. I've not looked into this issue for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get the callers' variables, but you can get their arguments. This is easily done with [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace):

```
<?php

class DebugTest
{
    public static function testFunc($arg1, $arg2) {
        return self::getTrace();
    }

    private static function getTrace() {
        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        return sprintf(
            "This trace function was called by %s (%s:%d) with %d %s: %s\n",
            $trace[1]["function"],
            $trace[1]["file"],
            $trace[1]["line"],
            count($trace[1]["args"]),
            count($trace[1]["args"]) === 1 ? "argument" : "arguments",
            implode(", ", $trace[1]["args"])
        );
    }
}

echo DebugTest::testFunc("foo", "bar");
```

Running this program, we get this output:

```
This trace function was called by testFunc (/Users/mike/debug.php:23) with 2 arguments: foo, bar
```

`debug_backtrace()` returns an array; element 0 is the function in which the function itself was called, so we use element 1 in the example. You can use a loop to travel all the way back up the trace.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of, but not in a way that would be wise to use in production code.

> In both examples it saves having to have an extra argument.

It would make your code very hard to understand, as you would break the implied encapsulation that a function has.

That all said, you might use a global variable for this?