# Accessing class properties

Tags: php, oop

How do i access the properties of class A from an object instantiated inside class A.

## Like this;

```
class A()
public var1;
public obj1;

function __construct(){
  $this->var1 = 'Hello World';
  $this->obj1 = new B();
}
```

==============

```
class B()

function anything(){
   #i want to access var1 from the calling class here ????
   # how do i access var1 in the calling class
}
```

Comment: *(reference)* [Classes And Objects - The Basics](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: *(related)* [Learning OOP](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=learning+oop+php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out which class called a method in another class.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214043/find-out-which-class-called-a-method-in-another-class)

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct way to do this. Dependency injection is a possibility:

```
class B {

    protected $A = null;

    public function __construct($A) {
        $this->A = $A;
    }

    public function foo() {
        $this->A->var1;
    }

}

class A {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->obj1 = new B($this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that this type of cyclic referencing can cause problems when trying to unset the instance in PHP prior to 5.3