# Getting a class name from iside a another classe's method

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods, static-classes

I would like to know if there is a way to access information when a method is called from inside a class.

#### Example.

Here I have a class, with a `__classStatic()` method, to generate arbitrary methods.

```
class Caller
{
  public function __callStatic($func, $args){
       echo "method $func is being called from class ..."; 
  }
}
```

Now, Whenever a method is called ex:`Caller::foo()` inside say.. a class named `Reader`,

```
class Reader{
    Caller::foo(); 
}
```

I would like `foo() to output.

> method foo is being called from class Reader

So, the problem is getting the call name from which a method is being called.

I tried inside foo() to get the class name using:

```
get_class()
get_parent_class()
get_called_class()
```

But, none of provide any information that I am looking for.

Comment: [`__CLASS__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol What if `SubCaller` extends `Caller` ? `__CLASS__` isn't correct

Comment: @CONtext or some nasty backtracing ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214043/find-out-which-class-called-a-method-in-another-class

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol [That wont work](https://eval.in/170491)

Comment: @CONtext It *would* have worked, if you'd actually typed what you meant to type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no language construct in PHP to achieve this. To do it you would need to analyze the stack trace:

```
class Callee
{
    public static function __callStatic($func, $args){
        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        for($i = 1; $i < count($trace); $i++) {
            $x = $trace[$i];
            if($x['function'] === $func && is_a($x['class'], __CLASS__, true)) {
                continue;
            }
            $class = $x['class'];
            break;
        }
        return "method $func is being called from class $class";
    }
}

class Foo extends Callee
{
}

class Reader
{
  function doSomething(){
      echo Foo::foo();
  }
}

(new Reader)->doSomething();
```

Output:

```
method foo is being called from class Reader
```

However, this performs very bad. Your application logic should not rely on this. For analytical purposes you might use a debugger.

---

*Original answer*, given because you first wrote that you expect:

> method foo is being called from class Reader

You need to use `get_called_class()`:

```
class Caller
{
  public static function __callStatic($func, $args){
       echo "method $func is being called from class " . get_called_class();
  }
}
```

Also note, that `__callStatic()` needs to be declared `static`. Btw, the class name `Caller` sounds weird. I guess you meant `Callee`.

Comment: The output of this will be `Caller` while OP wants it to be `Reader`. That seems like an interesting question.

Comment: Damn! he edited the question after I answered!!!! Before he wroted `Caller` is expected.

Comment: @hek2mgl Sorry :) I didn't change the question overall. Just some logic

Comment: @CONtext You *completely annihilated* the meaning of the question. Next time, ask what you *mean* to ask so you don't end up wasting people's time like this.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You are right. But check the example of my last comment to see the difference between `__CLASS__` and `get_called_class()` in action

Comment: @hek2mgl Yeah, this does answer the question but as you stated, it does seem very bad, and sloppy approach. I don't like foo extending Caller at all. but +1 until someone can give a better answer (if any) thanks

Comment: I just wanted to show that I took inheritance into account. Maybe you even don't want that in real life scenarios. However, a better way would be just pass the calling class as an argument to the function.