# How can I use a PHP editor for debugging?

Tags: php

I am having difficulty manually debugging my code. Which editors support debugging PHP code, and how do I use them?

Comment: @BoltClock There are some pretty good answers down there, so I submitted an edit to the question to possibly make it higher quality. Please have a look at my edit and if you think it looks good, consider re-opening the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Eclipse PDT](http://eclipse.org/pdt/) as IDE, and it supports debugging *(for both web-pages and command-line scripts)*, using the [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) extension *-- and Zend Debugger, should I add, even if I have never used it*.

There are tutorials available on the net explaining how to setup both of those to get the debugger working. For instance, you might want to read :

- [How To Setup a Free PHP Debugger using Eclipse PDT + XDebug](http://robsnotebook.com/php_debugger_pdt_xdebug)
- [Setting up Eclipse to Debug Drupal with XDebug](http://echodittolabs.org/drupal-xdebug-pdt-eclipse) *(unfortunatly, the screenshots are missing)*
- Or *(in french, but with screenshots ; so, might be helpful even if not easy to understand)* :

  - [Débugger avec WampServer, Xdebug et PDT](http://blog.wampserver.com/index.php/2009/08/28/debugger-avec-wampserver-xdebug-et-pdt/)
  - [Configurer Xdebug pour Eclipse PDT en utilisant un serveur de test distant](http://blog.christophelebot.fr/2008/11/02/configurer-xdebug-eclipse-pdt-serveur-test-distant/)

And here is a screenshot of what it can look like *(here, I've set a breakpoint somewhere is the admin section of Dotclear)* :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/eclipse-xdebug-debug-1.png))</sub>

I've used Eclipse PDT + Xdebug successfully on several projects, based on several Frameworks -- the last in date being a project based on Drupal.

Comment: Backing you up 100% on Eclipse PDT. Best cross-platform editor available, in my opinion anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans, along with many others have XDebug Support.

http://xdebug.org/docs/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xdebug

Answer (score 1):

Most PHP IDEs have integrated support for some debugger or the other.

Maybe these questions prove helpful:

- [**How do you debug PHP scripts?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts)
- [**Any good PHP IDE, preferably free or cheap?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166/any-good-php-ide-preferably-free-or-cheap)

Answer (score 1):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) has a [DBGP plugin](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central) that works just fine with [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). Couldn't live without.

Answer (score 1):

[**Netbeans**](http://netbeans.org/) is free, cross-platform and compatible with X-Debug.

Here's instructions on how to configure them: http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

Also, for paid IDEs, I've enjoyed using **PHPDesigner** in the past. I also hear **PHPNuke** is very good. All support X-Debug.