# How to debug PHP code under Linux when just an blank page is shown?

Tags: php

I am newbie on PHP.
Here is my situation: I write my code in vim and put it under `/var/www/` then I visit this to run my code on browser:

```
http://localhost/***.php
```

When my code has a bug, it shows a blank page.

How can I debug my code like C++ or Java?

Thanks.

**Edited:**

The link some friends provide is not helpful for me. I am under Linux. That's for Windows.

Comment: using search is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243572/how-to-debug-php-code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you debug PHP scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts)

Comment: which is already a duplicate lol

Comment: This link is not helpful for me. I am under Linux. That's for Win.

Comment: @AlexNetkachov that question is deleted

Comment: I tried to edit the question to mention directly from the title that it was related to Linux. Also trying to put more details in the title since now this title is deprecated by Stack Overflow (it's not possible to save just "How to debug Php code?" now)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If on a localhost, I would suggest using firefox or chrome and installing firebug for mozilla, and chrome gets a default. Be sure that on a local host your settings are matched to the server you are uploading to as this can cause problems when going live.

Specifically most shared hosting has PHP on safe mode and output buffering off, so if you use it, use it by calling it by calling ob_start(); etc, otherwise you should have no problems, and learning to debug is part of the fun, helps you learn alot :)

As for php errors just re-edit your php.ini file, you can find al relevant information on http://php.net

Happy Coding

Answer (score 15):

include this both line in code to see what kind of error is.

```
<?php 
       ini_set("display_errors",1);
       error_reporting(E_ALL);
        //code goes here
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

For more advanced solution, you can use [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) extension for PHP.

By default when XDebug is loaded, it should show you automatically the backtrace in case of any fatal error. Or you trace into file (`xdebug.auto_trace`) to have a very big backtrace of the whole request or do the profiling (`xdebug.profiler_enable`) or [other settings](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings). If the trace file is too big, you can use `xdebug_start_trace()` and `xdebug_stop_trace()` to dump the partial trace.

**Installation**

Using PECL:

```
pecl install xdebug
```

On Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
```

On Mac (with Homebrew):

```
brew tap josegonzalez/php
brew search xdebug
php53-xdebug
```

Example of mine configuration:

```
[xdebug]

; Extensions
extension=xdebug.so
; zend_extension="/YOUR_PATH/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
; zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.20/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so" ; MAMP

; Data
xdebug.show_exception_trace=1       ; bool: Show a stack trace whenever an exception is raised.
xdebug.collect_vars = 1             ; bool: Gather information about which variables are used in a certain scope.
xdebug.show_local_vars=1            ; int: Generate stack dumps in error situations.
xdebug.collect_assignments=1        ; bool: Controls whether Xdebug should add variable assignments to function traces.
xdebug.collect_params=4             ; int1-4: Collect the parameters passed to functions when a function call is recorded.
xdebug.collect_return=1             ; bool: Write the return value of function calls to the trace files.
xdebug.var_display_max_children=256 ; int: Amount of array children and object's properties are shown.
xdebug.var_display_max_data=1024    ; int: Max string length that is shown when variables are displayed.
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=3      ; int: How many nested levels of array/object elements are displayed.
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0             ; int: Show the difference in memory usage between function calls.

; Trace
xdebug.auto_trace=0                 ; bool: The tracing of function calls will be enabled just before the script is run.
xdebug.trace_output_dir="/var/log/xdebug" ; string: Directory where the tracing files will be written to.
xdebug.trace_output_name="%H%R-%s-%t"     ; string: Name of the file that is used to dump traces into.

; Profiler
xdebug.profiler_enable=0            ; bool: Profiler which creates files read by KCacheGrind.
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/log/xdebug"  ; string: Directory where the profiler output will be written to.
xdebug.profiler_output_name="%H%R-%s-%t"      ; string: Name of the file that is used to dump traces into.
xdebug.profiler_append=0            ; bool: Files will not be overwritten when a new request would map to the same file.

; CLI
xdebug.cli_color=1                  ; bool: Color var_dumps and stack traces output when in CLI mode.

; Remote debugging
xdebug.remote_enable=off            ; bool: Try to contact a debug client which is listening on the host and port.
xdebug.remote_autostart=off         ; bool: Start a remote debugging session even GET/POST/COOKIE variable is not present.
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp          ; select: php3/gdb/dbgp: The DBGp protocol is the only supported protocol.
xdebug.remote_host=localhost        ; string: Host/ip where the debug client is running.
xdebug.remote_port=9000             ; integer: The port to which Xdebug tries to connect on the remote host.
xdebug.remote_mode=req              ; select(req,jit): Selects when a debug connection is initiated.
xdebug.idekey="xdebug-cli"          ; string: IDE Key Xdebug which should pass on to the DBGp debugger handler.
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log" ; string: Filename to a file to which all remote debugger communications are logged.
```

Comment: Shall i know about how to debug in windows? Thanks  @kenorb

Comment: You can install XDebug in Windows as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your code...

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You will also want [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) on in `php.ini`.

Note that you should have public facing error reporting off in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Though i personally find var_dump just enough for my php debugging, some people tend to like using debuggers like xdebug to do so.

Answer (score 1):

PHP produces an `error_log` file in its directory whenever a problem occurs, you can find debug information there.

Also, try using `var_dump($someVarible)`.  This will give you useful information about the current state of a variable - often better than `echo`.

Comment: This all depends on your settings, he should first compare his virtual to his live server to ensure all similaritys are in place to avoid confusion when going live.

Comment: Well yes, but by default this will be true.

Comment: That depends on what virtual server he is using, and if he has set up a mirror to replicate his actual hosting it may not be so. Best to make sure, too many times I have created on localhost, and found many problems when going live.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comments about using  `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your code, I like to use the php cli utility.  I don't have a web server on the pc that I use to write and debug php and html, so a nice feature of the cli utility is the built-in web server.  To install the php cli:

```
sudo apt install php7.0-cli
```

To use the web server, cd to the directory where your html and php files are located and run:

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

Then point your browser to the files you're testing...for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/test.php
```

You can also use the cli utility to run your php code, and it will display the errors by line number (use an editor that displays line numbers).  You may need to comment out and adjust code that depends on html calling it.

```
php test.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Use these two lines to debug (this will enable to find the errors on the line numbers):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: What does this answer bring that other answers don't have?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the log file output by PHP. A good way to see your configuration is to use [phpinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

Also you can set [error_reporting()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) so you can see the error message instead of a white page.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, if you set you `error_report`to -1 you'll be able to see all notices, warning and errors in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options:

- use the error_reporting() function to have your code report even the slightest warning. Alternatively look in the server's error log file.
- use var_dump(), print_r() and echo to look at your variables.
- use debug_backtrace() and debug_print_backtrace() to see your call stack.
- use xdebug. Xdebug provides debugging by using breakpoints and stepping through the code, tracing and profiling. Xdebug is a PHP extension. You can run it standalone by giving commands on the command line, an environment variable or an ini file.
- More user friendly is to use a program to interface with Xdebug. This interface goes by default via port 9003 (9000 in older Xdebug versions). Popular programs for this purpose are PHPStorm, Netbeans and Visual Studio.

Note that Xdebug seriously slows down your server. So switch it off when you don't use it.