# SQL select query works with phpMyAdmin but doesn't show any output with PHP web service

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table1 named 'residencial' and table2 named 'propert_data'.

In 'residencial' table, I have a column named 'main_cat' which can have 3 values i.e 'Residential', 'Commercial' and 'Land'.

I have 2 web services named commercial_data.php and residential_data.php

1) commercial_data.php:

```
<?php
require 'include/connection.php';

$sql="SELECT * FROM residencial INNER JOIN propert_data ON propert_data.r_id = residencial.pid WHERE residencial.main_cat= 'Commercial' AND propert_data.meta_key = 'slider_images'";

 $rows = array();
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($rows,$row);
}
$myJson = json_encode($rows);
echo $myJson;

?>
```

Output of this is perfect.

2) residential_data.php:

```
<?php
require 'include/connection.php';

$sql="SELECT * FROM residencial INNER JOIN propert_data ON propert_data.r_id = residencial.pid WHERE residencial.main_cat= 'Residential'
    AND propert_data.meta_key = 'slider_images'";

 $rows = array();
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    array_push($rows,$row);
}

$myJson = json_encode($rows);

echo "Data:". $myJson;

?>
```

Output of this is: `Data:`

The only difference in two file is:

In file 1, I have: `residencial.main_cat = 'Commercial'`

In file 2, I have: `residencial.main_cat = 'Residential'`

What could the problem be?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you tried debugging your code? Are there faults in your table structure which prevents it to be correctly encoded to JSON? From the looks of it, your code seems alright but you need to debug it. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710665/how-to-debug-php-code)

Comment: Thanks will see if it works..

Comment: `$sql="SELECT * FROM residencial INNER JOIN propert_data ON propert_data.r_id = residencial.pid WHERE residencial.main_cat= 'Residential'
    AND propert_data.meta_key = 'slider_images'";` does this query have result in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly fine in phpmyadmin..

Answer (score -1):

You can Use like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}
```