# unable to split Arabic Alphabets

Tags: php

i need to split Arabic text am trying different methods but not solved it

```
$input = "ابجد";
$split = mb_str_split($input);
print_r($split);
```

am expected output like

```
(ا،ب،ج،د)
```

need solution

Comment: [How to debug Php code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710665/how-to-debug-php-code), When you use that you should get a warning like: "**Warning: Array to string conversion**", because the output of `str_split()` is an array, you should not use that value the way you do now....

Comment: Its because your file/form is in unicode character, that need to be in utf-8 .. Can you share your html code

Comment: sir its normal code am used in function not used in html am add in header utf-8 all other working fine but split not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `implode` for *output=(ا،ب،ج،د)* :

```
 $input = "ابجد";
 $split = mb_str_split($input,1,'UTF-8');
 print "(".implode('،',$split).")";
 //output: (ا،ب،ج،د)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [mb_str_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-str-split) which can process [multibyte strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php). This code:

```
$input = "ابجد";
$split = mb_str_split($input);
print_r($split);
```

results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ا
    [1] => ب
    [2] => ج
    [3] => د
)
```

When you manipulate (trim, split, splice, etc.) strings encoded in a multibyte encoding, you need to use special functions since two or more consecutive bytes may represent a single character in such encoding schemes. Otherwise, if you apply a non-multibyte-aware string function to the string, it probably fails to detect the beginning or ending of the multibyte character and ends up with a corrupted garbage string that most likely loses its original meaning.

You can reverse the output by using [array_reverse()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php), like this:

```
$input = "ابجد";
$split = mb_str_split($input);
$reversed = array_reverse($split);
print_r($reversed);
```

The output now is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => د
    [1] => ج
    [2] => ب
    [3] => ا
)
```

See: https://3v4l.org/ZsJNb

Comment: sir am trying but this solution not workig

Comment: @qaiserjutt _"not working"_ is a poor description of a problem. I will add something to reverse the output, if that was the problem.