# Debug Web Page PHP

Tags: php, debugging

I would like to ask, If  open a Web page from IDE say Phped, then I s it possible to go back to debug session by clicking a link on web page, so that I can run through code.

If possible can you please guide me.

Assume that I have set up my .htaccess folder like  abc.html  >>>index.php

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

To debug a PHP script, use [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/php/) with [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org).

Following links are going to help you.

- http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html
- http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

Similar question - [How do you debug PHP scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts)