# Is there an Easy out of the box solution to debug PHP?

Tags: php

I am writing a php web application and I get stuck because my script doesn't work how I would expect.  Then I check the logs and I get nothing.  My php.ini file is set to display all errors and log all errors.  But I am not getting anything.  On my mac, how can I debug PHP so I can step through the code and see what the problem is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you debug PHP scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts)

Comment: echo 'stuff is working'. But seriously, I'm interested if anyone has a good answer besides that, and besides installing a PHP debugging framework, because I'm not aware of any easy way

Comment: Need to be careful with that php.ini for displaying errors, if it's set like that on production you will end up in a world of hurt. Also you should take a look at XDebug (http://xdebug.org/).

Comment: This is only for development, not production.

Comment: is the error reporting directive set to E_ALL | E_STRICT? how do you know that there is actually an error occuring?

Comment: Are you sure that php.ini is being used.  Did you check `phpinfo()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use apache then look into apache logs.

Comment: I have looked in the logs and I don't see any new messages related to my issue.