# I cannot add data to MySQL from my PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, database

I was creating my website so I tried registering users for my website. I created MySQL database and wrote who codes and query. I then first tried to register a sample user, It was successful, then I tried one more but it was not successful. I didn't changed any query or something. My code was as it is but I don't know what happened.

My PHP code in registered.php

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","accessdenied")
  or die ("Couldn't connect to server");

$db = mysql_select_db("hdnesslife",$connection)
  or die ("Couldn't select database");

$fname =$_REQUEST["fname"];
$lname =$_REQUEST['lname'];
$username =$_REQUEST['username'];
$email =$_REQUEST['email'];
$password =$_REQUEST['password'];


$order = "INSERT INTO users(fname,lname,username,email, password)VALUES('$fname','$lname','$username','$email','$password')";
$result = mysql_query($order);

if($result){
echo("<br>Success");
}
else {
    echo("<br>No Success");
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

My HTML form code in register.php

```
<form action="registered.php" method="post">
    First Name<input required="required" type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
    <br>
    Last Name<input required="required" type="text" name="lname" id="lname">
    <br>
    Username<input required="required" type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <br>
    Email Id<input required="required" type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <br>
    Password<input required="required" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="password">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="register">
</form>
```

Every time I try to register a new user, It says

> "No Success"

It seems that the $order query is wrong but I have checked many times.
I have checked the code many times and it seems correct I don't know what's the problem it, Please help me.

Comment: What does your table look like ??

Comment: You should print `$order` after you set it to have your exact sql query. Then run it in phpmyadmin, it will tell you what is wrong in your query

Comment: As your starting with this I suggest you read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php to take a good start

Comment: Actually, your code is, on the face of it, fine. But it's incredibly vulnerable, so you should definitely take steps to protect it.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to find problems if you see a proper error message. Either use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts) (recommended) or put debug statements to your code. You could for example do

```
echo mysql_error($connection);
```

right after echo `"<br>No success";`.

mysql_error will print out the last error that happened on a specific connection, or if no identifier is supplied the last opened connection. Read more at the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php).

**Warning:** The mysql extension is deprecated. While you have the chance, you should switch library to for example mysqli. Read more at here: [Choosing an [MySQL] API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you outputted the error from MySQL, it will tell you what's wrong!

Change the line:

```
$result = mysql_query($order);
```

To:

```
$result = mysql_query($order) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Yes - this is essential for development but remove this from the production code.