# Xdebug Notepad++ DBPG Plugin local and global context not showing

Tags: php, xampp, notepad++, xdebug

I am using Xdebug with the [DBGP Notepad++ plugin](http://sourceforge.net/p/npp-plugins/discussion/709026#)

I can add breakpoints fine, the watchlist will show arrays and sometimes objects and hovering over variables shows their values. However the local and global variables tabs don't show anything and whenever I hover over an object or it's method or refresh local context the plugin disconnects with an 'Undefined error' popup. No error seems to be printed in the xdebug log.

I am using Notepad++ 6.4.3, Xdebug 2.2.0, Php 5.4.4, Xampp on Windows with the Symfony2 framework.

My Xdebug settings are.

```
xdebug.auto_trace = 1
xdebug.collect_includes = 1
xdebug.collect_params = 1
xdebug.collect_return = 1
xdebug.default_enable = "On"
xdebug.extended_info = 1
xdebug.idekey = "xdebug"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 100
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.show_local_vars = 9
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 128
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the creator of the plugin and he says the plugin is broken because it hasn't been updated to work with newer versions of notepad++/xdebug and he hasn't got time to update it. You can see the discussion [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/npp-plugins/discussion/709026/thread/8ead2e56/)