# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 2

Tags: php, foreach

When trying to execute this code am getting an error like this

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line number 2

My code is:

```
<?php
$contacts= $getcontact_access->GetContacts($oauth, $access_token, $access_token_secret, false, true,$emails_count);
foreach($contacts as $k => $a)
 {
  $final = end($contacts[$k]);
   foreach($final as $email)
    {
     echo '<section style=" border-bottom:1px solid #d9d7d7; padding-left:150px">'.'<input class="label" value="'.$email["address"].'"  name="invite[]" type="checkbox" checked>'.$email["address"]."</section>";
    }
 }
?>
```

Have you any idea?

Comment: post count($contacts)

Comment: `$contacts` is not an array.

Comment: What does var_dump($contacts) say ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, general idea is to [debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts). You should check

```
var_dump($contacts);
```

and see what's inside.

*It's Friday so may be I'm too kind when doing debug for others*

Answer (score 0):

Yes....
I found its solution,

It will be.

```
<?php
$contacts= $getcontact_access->GetContacts($oauth, $access_token, $access_token_secret, false, true,$emails_count);
if (is_array($contacts))
{
foreach($contacts as $k => $a)
 {
  $final = end($contacts[$k]);
   foreach($final as $email)
    {
      echo '<section style=" border-bottom:1px solid #d9d7d7; padding-left:150px">'.'<input class="label" value="'.$email["address"].'"  name="invite[]" type="checkbox" checked>'.$email["address"]."</section>";
    }
 }
}
?>
```