# Export downloadable content wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

is there a way to export all the downloadable content from wordpress?

i found this code online for the post, but i need for the downloadable content, like all my PDF, wordfiles

```
    <?php

include "wp-load.php";

$posts = new WP_Query('post_type=any&posts_per_page=-1&post_status=publish');
$posts = $posts->posts;
/*
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT ID,post_type,post_title
    FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE post_status<>'auto-draft' AND post_type NOT IN ('revision','nav_menu_item')
");
*/

header('Content-type:text/plain');
foreach($posts as $post) {
    switch ($post->post_type) {
        case 'revision':
        case 'nav_menu_item':
            break;
        case 'page':
            $permalink = get_page_link($post->ID);
            break;
        case 'post':
            $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
            break;
        case 'attachment':
            $permalink = get_attachment_link($post->ID);
            break;
        default:
            $permalink = get_post_permalink($post->ID);
            break;
    }
    echo "\n{$post->post_type}\t{$permalink}\t{$post->post_title}";
}
```

can someone help me?

Comment: You already have the code for downloadable content: `case 'attachment':`. . . . Learn some [debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts) techiques

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress stores this content in the wp-content/uploads/ directory. You can pull all your content by downloading that folder using FTP or similar.

Comment: I would like to have a list of them , not the actual files.

Comment: A list containing what data?

Comment: word files, excel files, pdf and image files

Comment: sorry forgot to add, i am currently using this plugin for the downloading options. http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/download-monitor

Comment: So... you want a list of filenames?

Comment: yes, whatever files i have on my WP page now. i want to have them extracted.

Comment: Presumably, once you've downloaded the files you can create a list of them. If you have SSH access to the server and it's *nix, you can do this automatically with `find`