# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION while using YII C GridView

Tags: php, yii

I am getting the following error while using `yiicgridview`

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/.../result.php on line 23`

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(    
    'id'=>'product-table',    
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),    
    'columns'=>array(    
        array('header' => '#','value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)','headerHtmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'table-header-check')),    
        array('name'=>'testname'),    
        array('header'=> 'Subject Name','value'=>'$data->sub->subname'),
        array('header'=>'Validity', 'value'=>'$data->testfrom." To ".$data->testto'),
        array('header'=>'attemptedstudents',
              'value'=>function($data){
               $dataReader = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(stdid)as atstd FROM studenttest WHERE testid='.$data->testid.' AND status ="over"')->query();
               $atStd = $dataReader->read();
               return $atStd['atstd']; }),
        array('header'=>'Details',
              'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
              'template'=>'{details}',
              'buttons' => array (
              'details' =>array('imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/css/images/detail.png',
              'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("test/resultdetail", array("testid"=>$data->testid))',                          
              'options'=>array( 'class'=>'icon-manage')),
              ),    
        ),   
    ),    
    'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable',
    'cssFile'=>false,    
));?>
```

The error line code is  `'array('header'=>'attemptedstudents','value'=>function($data){';`
But this code is working perfectly in  the XAMP local host.
But it uploaded to server i am getting this error.
Any one please guide me ..

Comment: check your php version in XAMPP using `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and compare it with your production/live server's PHP version.

Comment: Discover [debug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts)

Comment: `'value'=>'$data->testfrom." To ".$data->testto'` - This string is incorrectly escaped - The values `$data` will not be resolved

Comment: @AlexP I have checked with commenting that line . The issue is in the next line

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax error.

Comment: @AlexP, thts not an issue, issue with that complex column, write that as a function in model or controller and then call it

Comment: @akhilnl, If you are using Anonymous functions you require PHP >= 5.3, perhaps the server is not on the same version?

Comment: @AlexP you are Right the server PHP version is 5.2.17 AND my local host is at  5.4.7 Thanks for the clue...

Comment: @akhilnl Glad I helped, I've added it as an answer if you wish to change your accepted one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) you require PHP >= 5.3

Answer (score 0):

> You can't write complex functions directly there. Write a function in
>   model or controller and then call that function instead.

please refer

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/278/cgridview-render-customized-complex-datacolumns/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
array('header' => 'attemptedstudents', 'value' => array($this, 'getData')
```

In Controller

```
public function getData($data) {
    $dataReader = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(stdid)as atstd FROM studenttest WHERE testid=' . $data->testid . ' AND status ="over"')->query();
    $atStd = $dataReader->read();
    return $atStd['atstd'];
}
```

Comment: Ya it will work thanks man ...But the real problem is the Php versions difference ..