# Can I find what files are using when a website page is ran?

Tags: php

I just received a source from my customer (it's written by PHP Generally), I try to read it and glance at database. I realize that it's very mess, some webpage's content is also saved in database. So, I want to find files are using by browser and I mean that php files, I want to edit them. Can I do that?

P/S: I'm sorry if this article bother you

Comment: tracing source code is one of the programmers' task. You can try to import the source codes to Eclipse, see if the IDE helps.

Comment: As I said above, "it's written by PHP Generally" - no framework

Comment: You can use debug tools to do this. Your browser is not one of them.

Comment: Can I use what debug tools? Please suggest for me :)

Comment: xdebug might do what you want, but also other things. You're better off doing your own research. This closed question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts

Comment: The [`inclued`](http://php.net/inclued) extension does exactly this.

Comment: I tried this but there was nothing display on screen :(

Answer (score 1):

Hi At any point you need to know what functions, what includes and what arguments are being passed just use debug_print_backtrace() function in your code.

for further reading follow http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php