# Custom field function available in WordPress templates

Tags: php, wordpress

How to create a function in a custom page and use it in `single.php`?

I have the custom page `mypage.php`

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Form */   

...

$myname = add_post_meta( $date, 'My Name', $name, true );

function name(){
if ($myname != ''){
    echo ="Hello World! ";
 }
}

get_header(); ?>

...
?>
```

Single page

```
<? php name(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have functions available in all [theme template files](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), you need to put them inside the file `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/functions.php`.

Just move your function to it, and call it in any template (single, page, archives, category). Check the documentation: [Functions File Explained](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained).

And to make the logic of your code work, you'd need to use [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) in the function:

```
function name(){
    $myname = get_post_meta('My Name');
    if ($myname != ''){
        echo "Hello World! ";
    }
}
```

PS: it's a bit strange that you're setting a post meta everytime the `mypage.php` template is loaded...

Comment: Thx, but why not work this code:     if ($myname != ' '){
        echo $myname;
    }

Comment: You need to learn debugging techniques in [WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and [PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts). Suggestions: try to use post meta names in low case and no spaces, ie, `*_post_meta('my_name')`; try to check for `isset($myname)`; and do a `var_dump($myname)`. Look in PHP manual to know more about this functions. Also, look in your HTML source code, you're echoing this before the `<body>`.