# If and else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

Hi I'm trying to set certain messages if certain targets aren't met but seems like my If statement wasn't implemented properly can anybody assist please... I would also like to know what should I do to round of my answers so that it don't show any decimals after the comma...

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$min = ($_GET["pop"] * 20 / 100);
$max = ($_GET["pop"] * 100 / 20);
?>

You are protected from players with lower than
 <?php if ($min = < 4 ) {echo "Nobody";} else {
echo $min;} ?> pop.<br>
You are protected from players with bigger than 
<?php if ( $max = > 382836 ) {echo "Nobody"} else { echo $max;} ?> pop.

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the output on this two if's and what do you expect?

Comment: Please use a debugger for this type ("My IF isn't working - why") of question. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts) question for help.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're using the wrong comparison operators (those operators aren't defined in PHP, or any language that I know of for that matter!). You need `$min <= 4`, not `$min = < 4`. Similar you need `$max >= 382846`, not `$max = > 382836`.

There's also a semi-colon missing on one of your lines (should be `{echo "Nobody";}` with a semi-colon at the end).

Comment: Thank you problem solved. Stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

use of operator is incorrect. `= <`should be `<=` and `= >` should be `>=` .
Try this

```
<?php 
if ($min <= 4 ) {
    echo "Nobody";
} else {
    echo $min;
} ?>

<?php 
if ( $max >= 382836 ) {
    echo "Nobody";
} else {  
   echo $max;
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed the compare-operators. It has to be
`>= or <=`

```
if($min <= 4) { 
    echo "Nobody";
}
else {
    echo $min;
}
```

and of course the other if-statement:

```
if($max >= 382836) {
    echo "Nobody";
}
else {
    echo $max;
}
```