# Negative value error in limit clause

Tags: mysql

I'm getting an negative value error all the time from MySQL, when I run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `nuke_multiheadlines_news` ORDER BY `news_status` ASC, `news_pubdate` DESC LIMIT -11800, -11795
```

[index.php](http://www.bestbuildpc.org/bugfiles/index.txt)

I still get the same error and looks like there is something wrong but I can not find it.

Comment: You can't use `LIMIT` with negative numbers, what are you trying to do?

Comment: The module works properly but I am getting this stupid error all the time. How can I fix this issue? This module pulls the news from google, yahoo and severals links from the feed.

Comment: You need to identify how the module returns `-11800, -11795`.

Comment: Can you check if there  is any mistake in the file to download. I'm working with this file from weeks and I got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you run in to problems because you're using negative values in your `LIMIT` clause, from the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).

Try changing the `LIMIT` clause to only use nonnegative numbers:

```
SELECT * FROM `nuke_multiheadlines_news` 
ORDER BY `news_status` ASC, `news_pubdate` DESC 
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: Yes I do know but where exactly. I have losts of DESC. Please specify! I posted the link to download. I need to know where.

Comment: @user2583893 - Read the documentation. You need to change the negative values in your `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: This is what I did and I am not getting any more error: $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `' . $prefix . '_multiheadlines_news`' . $string . ' AND `news_status` = 1 ORDER BY `news_pubdate` DESC LIMIT 0, 5';//LIMIT 0, 5

Comment: The error came back. I am so dissapointed. Let me know what I must do.

Comment: I only get this :October 5, 2014, 6:54 pm File: /www.bestbuildpc.org/db/mysqli.php - Line: 201
Code: 1064 - Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-11820, -11815' at line 1
SQL was: SELECT * FROM `nuke_multiheadlines_news` ORDER BY `news_status` ASC, `news_pubdate` DESC LIMIT -11820, -11815
 remote addr: 66.249.65.132

Comment: You will have to find out on which line number the query that is failing is located. Check out these posts for information about debugging your php scripts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts and http://php.net/manual/en/debugger.php

Comment: I did lots of changes but unfortunately I get the error back again. it is frustrated!! Let me know if you have any solution about it. Code: 1064 - Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-18450, -18445' at line 1
SQL was: SELECT * FROM `nuke_multiheadlines_news` ORDER BY `news_status` ASC, `news_pubdate` DESC LIMIT -18450, -18445
 remote addr: 66.249.69.32