# Converting double quotes to single quotes

Tags: php, quotes

I am little stuck today trying to convert double quote into single quote.

I got this:

```
$string=" WHERE news_cat='$catid' AND news_title LIKE '%$searchnews%'";
```

I did this but it didn't work:

```
$string = ' WHERE `news_cat` = \'' . $catid . '\' AND `news_title` LIKE '%$searchnews%'';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to escape the last single quotes:

```
LIKE \'%'.$searchnews.'%\'';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was very close but never thought of doing this one. lol

Comment: I wonder if you can help with this one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161065/negative-value-error-in-limit-clause: This the whole file www.bestbuildpc.org/bugfiles/index.txt