# Which script is writing output in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, xdebug

I'm working on a Laravel application and after some updates I keep getting a comma "," in every http response or console output so I'm crazy trying to find which script file is printing that character.

Is it possible to know which file is writing to the output http response or console?

---

**UPDATE**

I've put an echo call in Composer's **ClassLoader** `vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php` after an include function for the loaded classes is called, as follows:

```
/**
 * Scope isolated include.
 *
 * Prevents access to $this/self from included files.
 */
function includeFile($file)
{
    include $file; echo $file . "\n";
}
```

And now the comma appears between the following classes are loaded, is this helpful?

```
C:\Users\Bla\Bla\trunk\vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Handler/PrettyPageHandler.php 
,C:\Users\Bla\Bla\trunk\vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/AliasLoader.php 
C:\Users\Bla\Bla\trunk\vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Found it! As `@vladsch` said, it was before an opening tag `,<?php` in one of my config files, thanks

Comment: yes, do die() on each part of code (better then use xdebug for this) and look in view

Comment: Maybe the die() function for this task in laravel  is more hard than xdebug, xdebug automatically goes under all call functions and methods in all the chain of loaded files. With die you need manually to do that.

Comment: Search your entire app for two commas (,,) you might find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have it in HTTP and console then this rules out the views.

The culprit is probably a comma inadvertently inserted before the opening `<?php` tag. Most likely one of the first ones that is at the top of every PHP file.

Do a search for `,<?php` or for regex pattern `/\s*,\s*<\?php/`

Comment: To answer your direct question: potentially every script is writing output if it includes any text outside of the `<?php` and `?>` tags. A debugger won't help you in that case since php buffers its output. You won't see the output until the buffer is dumped unless you turn off buffering.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, [debugging with xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) or other debbuger tool, step by step (step into) until you find the script.

See this [stackover entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts) for guiadance.

I strongly recommend use a real debug tool as a good pro practice. But maybe for this particular purpouse its a little overwelming.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably narrow it down with some basic debugging. Add a `dd('hello')` throughout your application.

I would start in the `routes.php` file. See if the comma appears before or after the `hello`. If it is before the hello, then the comma is in one of the bootstrapping files.

If the comma is after the hello, then it is most likely in one of your views etc. Keep moving the `dd('hello')` deeper into your application until it appears.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I write in the update the comma seems to appear between two preloaded classes while bootstraping, any hint?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot, that's why you should use a version control system (i.e.: git), so you can easily rollback whenever the system breaks.

In your case you could try to search for comma inside every single files of your working directory (escluding vendor and other unimportant folders such as storage)

If you have a debugger you could try to step into to check every single call from the beggining