# Can't load smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I'm trying to use Smarty in my project, and It doesn't work, all what I have - is infinite loading of the page.
I'm using pure php without any frameworks. I created folder 'vendor/Smarty' and puth there all Smarty files from official web site.

So, when I trying to require Smarty.class.php - everything is ok. PHP storm found it. But in browser I have infinite loading, without any errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to determine what your code is actually doing. no one can guess what's going on from your description - there is not enough information.  This might point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts

Comment: Check official [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/installing.smarty.basic.tpl) for how to properly set up Smarty.