# Laravel blade engine Call to undefined function()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am very new in **Laravel** and **PHP** and hope that somebody can help me.

I want to add this code:

```
<?php

    $atts = array(
        "id" => 3,
        "post_id" => $actor['id'],
    );
    rating_form( $atts );
?>
```

to **Laravel blade view** and I'm get this exception:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to undefined function rating_form()
```

Comment: where you have `rating_form` function?

Comment: You must define you function in helpers or somewhere else.

Comment: Learn to [debug PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/888/1230836), a fundamental part of writing code is knowing how to debug it

Comment: The function "rating_form" is in an external php file "inc.php" 

I'm include this file in the main.view with the following code:

<?php
    include('rating-form/inc.php');
?>

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! This works

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good way to include files in laravel. Change your composer file to load this file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        ...
     },
     "files": [
        "rating-form/inc.php"
     ]
}
```

Then run `composer dump-autload`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

the queue may have cached some of your source code (liek your helpers) and when you add new function, you need to restart the queue