# Calling node from a PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I'm trying to call a node script from a PHP script using `exec`:

```
$output = exec("/usr/bin/node /home/user/nodescript.js");
```

The nodescript.js being:

```
var Scraper = require('google-images-scraper');

var keywords = process.argv[2];

var scraper = new Scraper({
    keyword: keywords,
    rlimit: 10, // 10 p second
});
console.log("foo");
scraper.list(10).then(function (res) {
    console.log("bar");
    console.log(res);
});
setTimeout(function () {
    process.exit(1);
}, 20000)
```

But what I receive is the string "foo", and not the "bar". If I run the node script from command line, I do get "foo" and "bar". Somehow I don't receive any console output inside the function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49756235/

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you cant get the output of exec command directly. You need to define 2nd argument as in the docs.

```
exec("node yourfile.js", $output); 
echo implode("\n", $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this when executing python scripts.  For some reason the last line disappears.  Try adding `2>&1` to your script and change `exec` to `shell_exec` which will return a string including error output.  See if that helps.

`$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/node /home/user/nodescript.js 2>&1");`

I know that the `2>&1` allows for the script to pass error and debugging output to the standard output since they go through a error output.  I had to do this to debug my scripts and the last line reappeared.

Comment: No... still the same. I think it is more related to apache can't run the script the same way my user does.

Comment: Are you getting any error output?  Because that was my issue as well with python, passing errors allowed me to see permissions and directory issues so I could debug it.  What also helps is setting up environment variables with `putenv` by repeating what's in your `$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.6 is bundled with the phpdbg interactive debugger.
However, the [documentation URL](http://phpdbg.com/docs) points to an expired domain, at the moment, so, yeah.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36131176/370786