# Print error in file php on PC

Tags: php, debugging

I'm new in PHP. I run file.php on my PC with Firefox but I don't know how see error. What I can add to see it, is possible if I have this file on pc and not on server?

Maybe this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

or it works only on Apache?

I tried nothing because I don't know how solve it.

This my file.php

```
<?php
 include('wrapper.php');
 $apikey = "xxx7d7391d1e68e9680e6";
 voxmail_init($apikey);
 voxmail_user_subscribe(array('mail' => 'xxxxx@gmail.com','privacy' => 1));
?>
```

This file used api newsletter service (the code - for assistance of service - is ok) and `voxmail_user_subscribe` register the email address at newsletter. `wrapper.php` is file in same folder of file.php for use API of this service.

In this wrapper.php is there include other file `xmlrpc.inc` (also in same folder)

Now when I run file.php in my browser the only thing that I see is this:

```
**'xxxx@gmail.com','privacy' => 1));?>**
```

but the assistant servec tried my code and works... he ask me to show error log, but I don't know where is this log.

Comment: That's PHP code. I has to be inside the php file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you debug PHP scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts)

Comment: yes i put it inside my file.php but it didn't show errors

Comment: Do you also have a `<?php` somewhere? And an error to display?

Comment: Just opening a PHP file in a browser isn't going to work. It needs to be called via a SAPI such as the PHP CLI, mod_php (apache) or php-fpm etc.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes see now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those directives can be set in lots of different places, as explained at [Runtime Configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.php). You need to be aware of the different syntaxes:

- If you set them from PHP code, you have to compose valid PHP code, e.g.:

  ```
  <?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', true);
  ```
- If you set it in PHP configuration files (`php.ini` or `.user.ini`) you have to use valid *.ini syntax:

  ```
  error_reporting = E_ALL
  display_errors = On
  ```
- If you set it in Apache configuration files (`httpd.conf` or `.htaccess`) you have to use valid apache syntax:

  ```
  php_value error_reporting E_ALL
  php_flag display_errors On
  ```

It's worth noting that errors that prevent PHP code from running (such as parse errors) cannot be set from within PHP code.

My advice is to configure your local system-wide file for development (display all errors, log none) and configure your project for dual configuration (display in development, log in production).

---

Answer to updated question:

1. can't see any obvious reason why your code should trigger errors and notices. Are you sure it does? Have you tried with something that *should* trigger one such as `1/0;`?
2. If you can see PHP code in the browser, **your code is not running at all**.

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
error_log("You messed up!", 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
```

You can use

[error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) — Send an error message somewhere