# PHP code showing syntax error in IDE

Tags: php, ide, dreamweaver

I am using the following function as suggested by a friend here to get the innerHTML. While the function works fine and solves my purpose, it is showing syntax error in my IDE. I am not an expert in coding hence not able to figure out. Requesting help in correcting the code.

**My code:**

```
<?php

$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

$content = implode(
    "",
    array_map([$doc, 'saveHTML'], iterator_to_array($body->childNodes))
);

echo $content;
```

My IDE is showing error on this line `array_map([$doc, 'saveHTML'], iterator_to_array($body->childNodes))`

**UPDATE**

I use Adome Dreamweaver CS6 as my code editor.

[image]

Comment: Can you start by sharing the IDE name you use?

Comment: What is the specific error and what's the name of the IDE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Also see [**How do you debug PHP scripts**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts).

Comment: Also you see that the variable $doc is not defined anywhere. And what version of php are you using

Comment: @Akintunde $doc is already fined in the earlier part of the code. It is a long code I just pasted here the required part. I am using PHP Version 5.6.31

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dreamweaver CS6 PHP syntax version is 5.3. All 5.4 and later functions/syntax will not be available to it.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1393664

Longer explanation for this specific example, shorthand arrays aren't allowed in your editor. If you want the editor to stop complaining you can swap to `array()` or upgrade to the `CC` version.

This code will work fine if your actual server is running 5.4 or later.